# Convert LUA table/json to KEY=VAL

Tags: json, lua, key-value

I need to convert a lua table to KEY=VAL

e.g:

```
   local t1 = {
        t0 = "valt0",
        t1 = "valt1",
        tN = {
            t0key = "t0var",
            t1key = "t1var",
        }
    }
```

to be

```
t0="valt0", t1="valt1", tN_t0key="t0var", tN_t1key="t1var"
```

somebody have suggestions?

Comment: Why not simply use json dump?

Comment: You really need exactly that output? Better get/make some Lua/JSON serializator.

Comment: As I said: `I need to...`, it is to convert the jSON logs to LEEF format.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that loops through the table, checking if the value is table, in which case feed that table back into the same function. for anything that isn't a table, write it out to your new flattened table. Depending on how likely it is to happen, you might want to check there are no cyclic reference by tracking tables you've already iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

```
local t1 = {
   t0 = "valt0",
   t1 = "valt1",
   t2 = 42,
   tN = {t0key = "t0var",
         t1key = "t1var"}
}

local function convert(t)
   local arr = {}
   local cyclic = {}

   local function convert_subtable(t, prefix)
      assert(not cyclic[t], 'Cannot convert: cyclic reference detected')
      cyclic[t] = true
      for k, v in pairs(t) do
         k = prefix..tostring(k)
         if type(v) == 'number' or type(v) == 'boolean' then
            table.insert(arr, k..'='..tostring(v))
         elseif type(v) == 'table' then
            convert_subtable(v, prefix..k..'_')
         else
            table.insert(arr, k..'='..string.format('%q', tostring(v)))
         end
      end
      cyclic[t] = nil
   end

   convert_subtable(t, '')
   table.sort(arr)
   return table.concat(arr, ', ')
end

print(convert(t1)) --> t0="valt0", t1="valt1", t2=42, tN_t0key="t0var", tN_t1key="t1var"
```